# Does php have a line expansion macro like perl? __LINE__

Tags: php

Does php have a line expansion macro like perl?  `__LINE__`
What about one for the current file? `__FILE__`

Thank you.

Comment: have you just asked a question and answered it by yourself?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, PHP does have these `magic constants` as described [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php).

Comment: Thanks.  Glad someone's around to help.